# UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths blocks UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer

### Intro

I have `UIPanGestureRecognizer`created like this:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
[panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

and `tableView` with `NSTimer` that fires every 0.3 s to insert new row to `tableView` if new data appears in database.

Creation of `NSTimer` :

```
NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(onTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Inside `onTick` selector if new data appeared I perform simple row insertion:

```
    [_tableView beginUpdates];
    [_tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [_tableView endUpdates];
```

The `tableView` has disabled scrolling and user interaction.

### Issue

Calling `[_tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:]`makes `UIPanGesureRecognizer` unable to register any new touch event (panning and tapping). If I start to pan and then begin to add rows the panning doesn't break. I just can't start panning while rows are being added.

### Things I tried and facts

- Calling `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` in background using GCD doesn't work and also causes serious issues with in my app
- cells are created very fast so it's not a performance issue
- Starting to pan before inserting rows and then adding new cells doesn't make the panning choppy, the movement is still very smooth
- Changing row animation to `UITableViewRowAnimationNone` does nothing

Does anyone know why it happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` delegate method which always returns `YES` to allow the `tableView`'s internal `UIPanGestureRecognizer` work simultaneously with your `panRecognizer`:

```
panRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

Then

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

I also noticed that `insertRowsAtIndexPath` using animation takes approx. 1/3 second to complete but you call it every 0.3 sec. It may cause some problems as well. Try to update rows ONLY if there's new data to add to the table view:

```
- (void)onTick() {
    //your code

    if (shouldUpdate) {
        //do the updates only if there's new data to add to the table view
    }
}
```